# Azure CDN - Origin hostname not shown when Origin Type selected is Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn, azure-data-lake

Azure Data lake Storage hostname is not shown in the dropdown menu when I am trying to configure Azure CDN with Origin Type as Storage

Answer (score 1):

The origin Type of Azure CDN profile is：Storage, Web App, Cloud Service &Custom Origin. There is no Azure Data Lake at currently. And Azure Data Lake Store is still in preview. If you have any feature request, please submit in [Azure feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake).

Comment: That means Data lake store is not considered as part of Storage Origin type................. its really misleading which storage is it actually referring if its not generic to all storage of Azure. \

Comment: maybe it will be support in the future. If you want to know the detailed. I would suggest you get help from azure support. You could get easy access to Azure Support by going online to the Azure Portal and submitting a support request.