# Integrate Azure CDN with Azure Data Lake store

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-data-lake

How do I proceed in integrating my Azure CDN to read/pick files stored in Azure Data Lake store?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761466/azure-cdn-origin-hostname-not-shown-when-origin-type-selected-is-storage. At present we do not have the integration between CDN and Data Lake Store built in.

Comment: Amit Kulkarni - Yes that's correct there is no such integration at present ........... but what I wanted to know is , is there any possibility of delivering contents with min latency from Azure data lake.(with delivering contents I mean based on geographical locations)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake is still in preview and does not integrate with Azure CDN.